# Not getting the full text in output

Tags: python

I have 2 text files , from which I match the second column of txt1 with first column of txt2 before `|` , well I just mention it below , than I output if they are same , along with its discription , everything is going fine , but I didn't get the `new line discription` in the output , it just showed its first line.

Here is the content for **txt1.txt**

```
E5 E7 Bat
```

Here is the content for **txt2.txt**:

```
?E7|E5
Addsadsadsadsadsadsdasd
Sdsdfsdfdsfdsfdfdsfdsfd
AasadsaddccxcvcsAAGCAGT
```

This is the code which i am using

```
with open('txt1.txt', 'rb') as file1:
    #file1_data = dict(line.split()[1] for line in file1 if line.strip())
    file1_data = [line.split()[1] for line in file1 if line.strip()]
#print file1_data
with open('txt2.txt', 'rb') as file2, open('output.txt', 'wb') as outputfile:
    output = ""
    file2lines = file2.readlines()
    for i in range(len(file2lines)):
        line = file2lines[i]
        if line[0] == '?':
            row = line.strip().split('|')
            key = row[0][1:]
            if key in file1_data:
                output += line + "\t" + file2lines[i+1]
    outputfile.write(output)
outputfile.close()
```

`Getting output`

```
?E7|E5
Addsadsadsadsadsadsdasd
```

`Required output`

```
?E7|E5
Addsadsadsadsadsadsdasd
Sdsdfsdfdsfdsfdfdsfdsfd
AasadsaddccxcvcsAAGCAGT
```

Comment: At least provide us the files.

Comment: @CppLearner I provided it , if you see , with the name txt1 and txt2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need some state processing - "in matching block" / "not in matching block". I have rewritten second part of your algorithm:

```
with open('txt2.txt', 'rb') as file2, open('output.txt', 'wb') as outputfile:
    output = []
    do_block = False
    for line in file2:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if not line: continue
        if line[0] == '?':
            key = line.strip().split('|')[0][1:]
            do_block = key in file1_data
        if do_block:
            output.append(line)
    outputfile.write("\n".join(output))
```